# UIImageView не отображает изображение

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimage

В tableViewCell у меня есть UIImageView. 
Я получаю путь до изображения, расположенного локально, и пытаюсь создать UIImage из него следующим кодом:

```
let imagePath = recipe.value(forKey: "photoPath") as? String
cell.photo.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
```

При этом imagePath != nil и показывает путь до файла.
В чем может быть проблема?

Добавил промежуточное создание UIImage(). После скармливания ему пути до файла, UIImage не конструируется нормально, т.е. при

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
```

image равен nil.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для большей наглядности изменил код на следующий:

```
    var image: UIImage?
    let imagePath = (recipe.value(forKey: "photoPath") as? String)!

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imagePath) {
        if let newImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
            image = newImage
        } else {
            print("Warning: file exists at \(imagePath) :: Unable to create image")
        }
    } else {
        print("Warning: file does not exist at \(imagePath)")
    }
    cell.photo.image = image
```

Показывает, что файла по данному пути не существует

Comment: В пути видно что не хватает слеша между Documents и именем файла

Comment: @ViR , спасибо, что заметил
Но дело не в этом. Добавил слеш, но картинка все равно не загружается.

Comment: Нет информации откуда ты получаешь путь и есть ли данный файл на самом деле. imagePath это всего лишь строка пути, она не дает гарантии наличия файла.
Проверь через FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imagePath) наличие файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После того, как проверка на существование файла показала, что его нет, я решил посмотреть на путь.

После недолгого размышления поисков, выяснилось, что проблема была в том, как я получаю путь.

Корректным способом получения пути из UIImagePickerController'а для меня оказался следующий:

```
if let imgURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL {
        self.imagePath = imgURL.relativePath
    } else {

}
```